# Animation in CSS - Zoom in Zoom out and Spin at the same time

Tags: html, css

Trying to run both animations at the same time but only zoom in zoom out animation appears to work but not spin animation. Could anyone please help?

Here's the code

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px;
}

.animation {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  animation: spin 5s, zoomInZoomOut 2s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes zoomInZoomOut {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="animation"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `animation` on the `.container` to be able to display `spin` and `zoomIn` & `zoomOut`.

Also you need to set `position: absolute` on the container so its does not move while spinning.

**Demo:**

```css
.container {
  margin: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: zoomInZoomOut 5s infinite;
}

.animation {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  animation: spin 5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes zoomInZoomOut {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="animation"></div>
</div>
```